Should I customize the exception to check for formatting errors?
I'm considering using an exception to check email format, phone number, password, username in the registration function, and I'm debating between customizing the exception or not customizing it.
public class InvalidEmailFormatException extends RuntimeException{
    public InvalidEmailFormatException() {
        super("Invalid email format");
    }
    
    public InvalidEmailFormatException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class InvalidPhoneNumberFormatException extends RuntimeException {

    public InvalidPhoneNumberFormatException() {
        super("Phone number is invalid");
    }

    public InvalidPhoneNumberFormatException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class InvalidPasswordFormatException extends RuntimeException {

    public InvalidPasswordFormatException() {
        super("Password is invalid");
    }

    public InvalidPasswordFormatException(String mesage) {
        super(mesage);
    }
}



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just have 1 Exception and alter the message being passed in. No need to have different type of Exception for different messages in this instance. You probably want to add additional details as well explaining why the format is invalid
